# Does this logically follow?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Suppose it is given to be true that if $p_i | q_i$, then $p_i \nmid q_j$ for any $j\neq i$. Suppose it is also known that if $p_i \nmid q_i$, then $p_i | q_j$ for some $j\neq i$ is false whenever $p_i\nmid q_i$. Since any $p_i$ either divides $q_i$ or does not, there exists no scenario where $p_i|q_j$ when $j\neq i$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Basically you have for any $p_i$ either $p_i\mid q_i$ or $p_i$ does not divind any $q_i$ in the second set.

Comment: @fleablood, thank you. One concern I have is that since the contrapositive of a statement is equivalent in truth value, wouldn't taking the contrapositive of both statements show that the $p_i$ can never divide any $q_i$, producing a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

The first proposition can be put as

$$P_i \;\; \implies\;\; Q_{i,j}$$

the second is of the form,

$$not \; P_i \;\; \implies \;\; not \; Q_{i,j}$$
is false  so its negation

$$P_i \wedge Q_{i,j}$$
is true.

therefore, we cannot have $ not \;Q_{i,j}$.